# How can I duplicate a model and it's armature, so the rig still works?

Tags: armature, workflow

I need to make a duplicate of a character with its armature. When I try to duplicate the character, the duplicate remains associated with the original armature. When I make a duplicate of the armature, and try to associate the duplicate character with it, it fails. How can I accomplish this? Or is there a way to make duplicates of the character and the armature together, making the duplicate character associated with the duplicate armature?

Comment: this is done ^^

Comment: Thank you. So how do you combine the armature ? =)
They told me to move the model and the frame in a null block
And the create a group =/

Comment: I didn't actually know how to do this, so I had to experiment. The answer I posted is based on my understanding of your question, but since you also mention a frame, I'm not 100% certain. If it doesn't solve your issue, you should ask someone who knows both French and English to translate your original question.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you are in **Object mode**, then select **both** the character and the armature. First select one, then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting the other, then duplicate with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Do you have to be in object mode? That should probably be in your answer. (Unless my assumption is wrong.)

Comment: @TheMinecraftMan757 Yes, you have to be in object mode. In Edit mode, you only affect the object that you're editing, and in pose mode only bones can be selected. Thanks for pointing it out. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Update in Blender 2.8.
In Object mode, duplicate (Shift-D) the mesh and rig. In Object Data tab, in Armature field, with the new armature selected, click on the small icon on the right with the tootip "Display number of the users of this data (click to make a single user copy)". This lets you have a unique armature, that you can rename and manipulate without affecting the main one.

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of this? I'm looking at the `Object Data Properties` and not seeing anything related to Armature

Answer (score -1):

I'm a noob, so this is more a workaround than anything. No matter how many times I tried to duplicate an object with it's rig (and maintain parent/child relationships) I failed. Finally I created a new file and used file -> append to bring in two copies of the target object. Had to redo the parenting (that doesn't seem to survive append) but I did wind up with two objects each parented to its own rig. This probably wouldn't be practical for an extremely complex file, but it worked for a simple one..